# nested classes php or other method

Tags: php, private, chaining

I am looking for a method like the suggested php >=5.6 nested classes.

**example**

```
class Parent {

   public function call(){
       return new $this->Child;
   }

    class Child {

    }

}
```

Basically what I'm looking to do is something like

```
Secure::Encryption::Get();
```

or

```
Secure::Encryption($type)::Get();
```

You can do something similar in JavaScript ex:

```
function Secure(){

     return {
   Encryption: function(){
             return:{
                 Get:function(){}
             }
        }
     }
}
```

I want to have private members only accesible to the `Encryption` member. I know that nested classes are not possible yet so I'm looking for an alternative

Comment: You can use anonymous classes in PHP 7 if you want to wait :D

Comment: Oh yes I'll wait lol. Geesh php 5.6 hasn't even come out yet , or has it ??

Comment: try design pattern FACTORY CLASS

Comment: private members only accesible  <>  Secure::Encryption::Get(); - logical

Comment: @s.d.a.p.e not sure what you mean